# Is it possible to specialize a c++ template with base class type prior c++20?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, protocol-buffers, ros2

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct is_message : std::false_type {};


template<typename T>
class Publisher {
static_assert(is_message<T>::value, "This message type is not supported");
public:
  void Publish(T& msg) {}
};
```

previous code is a simplified sketch from a third-party library(ROS2 humble, and we are not supposed to change this codebase),
it uses type traits `is_message` to limit the message type to its generated IDL c++ messages, which generated codes to specialize the previouse type trait template like this:

```cpp
class GeneratedIdlMessageX {
public:
};
template<> struct is_message<GeneratedIdlMessageX> : std::true_type {};
```

Then the users can delcare working publishers like this:

```cpp
#include <ros2_headers.h>
#include <ros2idl_generated_message.h>

Publisher<GeneratedIdlMessageX> publisher;
```

Now the problem is we want to support protobuf messages as well, but we can not modify the protobuf IDL code generation to add this specialization.
As a result, we have to manually add this specialization on every protobuf message publishing declaration like this:

```cpp
#include <ros2_headers.h>
#inlcude <protobuf_generated_message.h>

template<> struct is_message<ProtoBufMessageY> : std::true_type {};

Publisher<ProtoBufMessageY> publisher;
```

How can I save this annoying work?

A straight idea is to introduce a predefined common header, which specialized all protobuf generated message for publisher users.
Considering all protobuf generated c++ message is inherited from `MessageLite`, I tried directly specialze the base class, and obviously it won't work:

```cpp
// of course this won't work
template <> struct is_message<protobuf::MessageLite> : std::true_type{};
```

Now I stucked here for not being able to modify thirdparty(ros2) and protobuf IDL generating code, appreciating any help.

NOTE: compile and running environment limits c++ standard below c++17(c++20 concept is not available).

Comment: use the `c++17` tag when you are restricted to a that standard version

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai c++ tag is added, thanks

Comment: ...But still mention the requirement explicitly in addition to the tag. If you forgot to state the requirement and are adding it later, it's a good idea to comment on the answers to tell them about it.

Comment: on the other hand you need not add "edit:" to  an edit. The question should have one consistent state (and yes, if an edit invalidates answers please notify them). If someone wants to see the edit hsitory they can do it here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77683781/revisions

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai thanks, edit questions to not manually showing edit history.

Answer (score 4):

C++20 concepts to the rescue:

```
template <std::derived_from<protobuf::MessageLite> T>
struct is_message<T> : std::true_type {};
```

In C++17 and earlier this is only possible with cooperation from the primary template, which must include a dummy template parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_message : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_message<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<protobuf::MessageLite, T>>>
    : std::true_type {};
```

If the library lacks this template parameter, it might be a good idea to report it as a bug.

Comment: Prior to C++20, you could also inherit from `std::bool_constant<std::is_base_of_v<protobuf::MessageLite, T>>` ... oh wait no, that wouldn't be a partial specialization. Oh well, C++20 really does save the day.

Comment: @JanSchultke how would you specialize it when you cannot modify the primary? https://godbolt.org/z/oPcr6ee8s ... overlapped edits :)

Comment: @JanSchultke Pre-C++20 you need cooperation from the primary template in the form of a dummy template argument: `typename = void`, then you can use `enable_if_t` in specializations.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, but the enviment is limited to c++17 and earlier, sorry for not metioning this at first.

Comment: @JanSchultke I know it doesn't work anyway, but I'm still curious about whether there are any reason to make the detour of `std::bool_constant`. Is there any reason not to directly inherit from `std::is_base_of<protobuf::MessageLite, T>`? Because that's the first idea that come to my mind when seeing the question restricted to c++17.

Comment: @WeijunZhou no, you could just inherit from that directly.

Answer (score 1):

In C++20, you could have used some of the other solutions. Unfortunately, your hands are tied in C++17.

A very dirty solution is this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Message;

template<typename T>
struct is_message<Message<T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
class Publisher<Message<T>> : public Publisher<T> {
public:
    using Publisher<T>::Publisher; // inherit all constructors
};
```

You define a partial specialization for both `is_message` and `Publisher` so that the `is_message` check succeeds.
This can then be used like:

```cpp
Publisher<Message<ProtoBufMessageX>> publisher;
```

This solution obviously has the downside that you need to use the `Message` wrapper for all protocol buffer messages.
To hide the ugliness of this, you can add a convenience alias:

```cpp
// If upgraded to C++20, this could eventually be turned into just
//   = Publisher<T>
template <typename T>
using PublisherType = Publisher<Message<ProtoBufMessageX>>;

PublisherType<ProtoBufMessageX> publisher;
```

The other option is to define an explicit specialization for each message separately, like you've suggested:

```cpp
template<> struct is_message<ProtoBufMessageX> : std::true_type {};
template<> struct is_message<ProtoBufMessageY> : std::true_type {};
template<> struct is_message<ProtoBufMessageZ> : std::true_type {};
// ...
```